# Is it possible receive messages in subscriptions synchronously in Azure service bus

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have 2 subscriptions to a Azure service bus topic. Both subscriptions receive messages in parallel and I have 2 Service Bus input triggered azure functions to process the messages.

**Azure service bus Topic**

--Subscription 1 -> Azure function 1

--Subscription 2 -> Azure function 2

But I have a scenario where, it would be better if my Azure function 2 picks up the messages after  Azure function 1 has finished processing the message.
One solution is to send the messages from Azure function 1 to a new topic and let Azure function 2 receive from the new topic.
Other than this, is there any other better solution to handle this ?

Comment: The solution you are describing is what I have seen the most for your scenario, and I think it is the best approach, not adding this as answer yet, in case someone comes with something better

Answer (score 1):

Agree with your solution that the easier way is to publish to a new topic from Function 1. This will work as the payload required is same for Function1 and Function2.

We faced a similar situation where we wanted Function1 to be completed before Function2 is processed. The payloads were different.
What we ended up doing is adding a condition in Function2 to check if Function1 has been completed and if not retry the message again after 5mins. Did this using the Lock-Expiry retry mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

What you mentioned is the easiest solution but you can also look into Durable functions. You will have to do more work but its meant for chaining functions which I think is your requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sequence?tabs=python